# Place image on a new page without top margin?

Tags: margins, article

I have an article:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
```

Now in a section I have a figure:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{images/rlexample.png}
\caption{---}
\label{rlexample}
\end{figure}
```

This figure is pretty big, so  I would like to show them in a single page without the classic top margin. Is there anyway to specify a negative top margin just for showing this figure?

### Solution

Thanks to Prof. @egreg the solution is (with pagenumber hiding)

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\vspace*{-3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{images/rlexample.png}
\caption{---}
\label{rlexample}
\end{figure}

\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: You can try adding `\vspace*{-3cm}` just after `\centering` (adjust to suit).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Also can I hide the page number ? Because it appears to be over my image. If you want make an answer i will accept

Comment: `\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}` will do the trick. Please post an answer I will accept it

Comment: And... Incredibile come grazie a stackexchange.com due italiani si siano incontrati qui :)

Comment: PS. the solutino with \pagestyle it isn't working well. (it hides page number on the previous page too) I have opened a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83860/remove-page-number-from-just-one-page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to make LaTeX think that the image takes less vertical space:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\vspace*{-3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{images/rlexample.png}
\caption{---}
\label{rlexample}
\end{figure}
```

In order to safely remove the header and footer, you need to use `fancyhdr` and its `\iffloatpage` macro.