# Remove page number from just one (float) page?

Tags: page-numbering

Basically I have some text:

```
\section{Section 1}

TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

Then I have an image:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{images/rlexample.png}
\caption{---}
\label{rlexample}
\end{figure}
```

This image takes a whole page so it's printed on a new page.
I would like to don't have page number on this page (where there is the image)

I have tried this after `\end{figure}`:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

But the page with text got no page number too.

How can I have page number on the page with text but not on the page with the image?

Comment: also relevant: [Suppress page number for a single page that only contains one large table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33007/579)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two ways: use `afterpage` or put `\thispagestyle{empty}` inside the `figure` environment as commented by Peter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Here is some text with an equation in it: $f(x)=x^2+3x_0\cdot\sin x$
and the textual content continues into the second line. No other math
content is contained within this paragraph.

\afterpage{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/rlexample.png}
\caption{---}
\label{rlexample}
\end{figure}
}

Here is some text with an equation in it: $f(x)=x^2+3x_0\cdot\sin x$
and the textual content continues into the second line. No other math
content is contained within this paragraph.

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{figure}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/rlexample.png}
\caption{---}
\label{rlexample}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

Note: Putting `thispagestyle{empty}` inside `figure` environment may need some `\clearpage` at appropriate places and may not work properly if `[p]` in `\begin{figure}[p]` is used as noted by Enrico. I would advice the use of `afterpage` though.

The code supplied in comment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{42}
\author{Jane Doe}
\date{June 2011}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{text}

text text \cite{B02} texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\afterpage{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\vspace*{-3cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{image.jpg}
\caption{caption}
\label{rlexample}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
}

\lipsum[1-10]


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\thispagestyle{empty}` method doesn't work for a page of floats, but only for floats that end in the same page where they are declared.

Comment: @egreg: Yes it won't work. Added to the answer. Thank you `:-)`

Comment: tried everything nothing worked

Comment: Take this miminmal example: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/50aea3ac3f475e415a1219cf currently the image is printed after the References page

Comment: @HarishKumar: Perfect now it's working. We were missing \clearpage in the figure.

Comment: When the page contains only a float, the "floatpag" package can be used: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33011/20929

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi 's suggestion works for me. Just `\usepackage{floatpag}` and then `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` inside `\begin{figure}[p]`.

Answer (score 8):

First add the package `\usepackage{floatpag}`.

Then you can use `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` within the figure environment. This will provide an empty page where the figure is.

Comment: add the package `\usepackae{floatpag}` to work the above said suggestion...

Comment: Thanks I added it

Comment: To me it appears as if including `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` is sufficient and affects all floats by default.