# Dynamically insert full-page image at nearest page break

Tags: floats, page-breaking

The situation: I have a document that essentially consists of many pages of plain text. I would like to include a full-page image at the page break nearest to a given line. It is important that the image be inserted at a pre-existing page break (i.e. that there not be 
excess trailing whitespace on the page preceding the inserted image).

In other words, I want to start with a document looking like this:

[image]

I would then like to be able to insert some sort of command in the text at the red mark that causes the image to be inserted at the nearest page break, thus giving me a result that looks like this:

[image]

The page containing the image should contain no other content (i.e. no header/footer/etc), and the image should be resized so that it fills the entire page (the images will already be of the correct aspect ratio).

---

Here's what I've tried so far. In all of these cases, `my_image.*` is an image that has been sized to the same aspect ratio as my document (in this case, `ebook`, which is 2:3, so my images are mostly 800x1200 pixels).

**First**, the naive approach:

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % to include the image-pdf
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[10] % some plain text
    \includepdf{my_image.pdf} % the image I want to be positioned somewhere around here
    \blindtext[10] % some more plain text
\end{document}
```

This obviously fails, because it inserts the image exactly at the position I requested, which may not be at a page break. I can of course manually futz with the positioning of the `\includepdf` so that it falls immediately after the end of the last paragraph that is immediately before a page break, but this is unpleasant and also not a practical solution since I have a somewhat large number of these images (at various positions throughout my document) to deal with.

**Second**, an approach that attempts to use floats:

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % to include the image-pdf
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[10] % some plain text
    \begin{figure}
        \includepdf{my_image.pdf} % the image I want to be positioned somewhere around here
    \end{figure}
    \blindtext[10] % some more plain text
\end{document}
```

What this ends up doing is it makes `my_image.pdf` the "background" of one of the pages rather than placing `my_image.pdf` on a separate page.

I then tried adding `\pagebreak` before `\begin{figure}`, before `\includepdf{my_image.pdf}`, before `\end{figure}`, and after `\end{figure}`; none of these did anything useful either.

**Third**, I tried using some code from [this tex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39148/31395), and futzing with vertical margins (based on looking at the output of the `layout` package):

```
\documentclass[ebook,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \adjustimg and \centerimg from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39148/31395>
\newcommand{\adjustimg}{% Horizontal adjustment of image
  \ifodd\value{page}\hspace*{\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\else\hspace*{-\dimexpr\evensidemargin-\oddsidemargin}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\centerimg}[2][width=\textwidth]{% Center an image
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\adjustimg\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[10]
    \begin{figure}
      \vspace{-\voffset} \vspace{-1in} \vspace{-\headsep} \vspace{-\topmargin} \vspace{-\headheight}
      \centerimg[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{my_image.jpg}
    \end{figure}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

This seemed to get the job done, but then I stuck it back into my original document, which has headers and footers. Add the following header/footer code to the preamble:

```
\makepagestyle{nstyle}
\makeevenhead {nstyle}{HEADER TEST LEFT}{MID}{RIGHT}
\makeoddhead  {nstyle}{HEADER TEST LEFT}{MID}{RIGHT}
\makeevenfoot {nstyle}{FOOTER TEST LEFT}{MID}{RIGHT}
\makeoddfoot  {nstyle}{FOOTER TEST LEFT}{MID}{RIGHT}
\pagestyle{nstyle}
```

This gives me the strange result that the headers are hidden (presumably behind the image?), but the footers display over the image. I don't understand why this would happen, but either way, it's a deal-breaker for me. This entire setup (what with the long series of `\vspace` and so forth) is extraordinarily inelegant anyway, so I assume this must not be a good way of approaching the problem anyway.

---

So at this point, I'm kind of at a loss for how to approach this problem. (I'm a total novice at latex, though, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's a straightforward solution I just don't know about.)

Note: I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm using `xetex` to compile (I need foreign script support).

---

EDIT: It seems likely to me that the best approach to solving this problem is to use `\includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment (i.e. some variant of the **third** approach I attempted above). The issues I'm facing are:

- I can't figure out how to remove headers/footers from the page that the `figure` ends up on. Or, alternatively, I can't figure out how to make the image appear "above" the footer (in the z-direction).
- I don't have a clean/elegant way of getting the graphic to occupy the entire page. If there isn't a clean/elegant way, so be it, though I do hope there's something better than throwing a series of 5 `\vspace`s at the problem.

(Note: I think my example above with the picture of the tree might have been misleading - the images I'm actually working with don't have a transparent or white background, and so it is important that there be no whitespace surrounding them. Ordinarily I'd deal with this using `pdfpages`, but I haven't found a way to get pdf pages to float properly.)

Comment: Why don't you include the picture with `\includegraphics` within a `figure` environment? And [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @mafp I think this is essentially what I did in the section labeled **third** (the `\centerimg` command is just a wrapper around `\includegraphics`). Anyway, I tried doing this with just `\includegraphics` instead of the `\centerimg` macro; this has the same issues with the footer appearing over the image, plus it requires me to futz with horizontal spacing so that there isn't whitespace in the left margin.

Comment: In your example, the image appears before the rubric (red mark).  Is that what you meant?  To have the picture possibly before or possibly after the rubric, depending on the location of the rubric on the page?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, that is what I mean. Ideally, the picture would appear before the page if the mark was in the first half of the page and after the page if the mark was in the second half of the page, but I'd be okay with a solution that e.g. always puts the picture after the page irrespective of the location of the mark on the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My immediate thought here is to use `\afterpage`. This should result in a placement one page after it's mentioned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,afterpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,lipsum,afterpage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\afterpage{
  \thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-a}%
}
\lipsum[21-40]
\end{document}
```

The above shows pages 3 and 4 (top), with the image inserted about two-thirds from the top on page 3. `\afterpage` then inserts a header/footer-less page (`\thispagestyle{empty}`) with the image stretched to the text block (`width=\textwidth,height=\textheight`) on a subsequent page. Adding `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` steps back the page counter so that the page seems to be literally inserted independently from the document flow (and may not be what you're after entirely, but something similar to `\includepdf` from [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)).

As far as I know, this use (with [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage)) should be free from problems with other unprocessed floats since it doesn't interface with the algorithm of float placement.

Of course, the image can also be made to fill the entire page. The answer is merely geared towards showcase the possibility.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but could you elaborate on _how_ the image could be made to fill the entire page? I tried putting `\newgeometry{hmargin=0,vmargin=0}` in the beginning of the `\afterpage` command, but that caused all sorts of new problems, and I don't really have any better ideas.

Comment: I managed to adapt your solution to my needs by replacing the line containing `\includegraphics` with `\includepdf[width=\paperwidth]{my_image.pdf}`, so I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: @senshin: That's great. I was thinking about stretching the image internally, but it's really not necessary. So you're approach with `\includepdf` is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?  I'm not sure (it's just using a float).  The figure will appear after the rubric, which I have indicated with a red capital R.  UPDATE, when I do as the comment indicates, my float works out just as I expect, on the page following the rubric.

Thanks to barbare beeton for the pointer on getting rid of a page number on the float page.  I used (I think) a variation of what was proposed there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\let\svthepage\thepage
\newcommand\rubric[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{R}%
  \def\thepage{\svthepage\thispagestyle{empty}}%
  \begin{figure}[p]%
  \includegraphics{#1}%
  \end{figure}%
  \afterpage{\global\def\thepage{\svthepage\let\thepage\svthepage}}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\rubric{example-image-a}
\lipsum[21-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To see how this was working, I replaced `[1-3]` with `[1-20]` and `[4-10]` with `[21-40]` (to get more lipsum text). When I compile this, I see the red "R" displayed in the middle of some text on page 4. The `example-image-a` is displayed on page 9. A solution to my problem would display the image either one page before or one page after what is currently rendered as page 4, so I don't think this answers my question. (Note: when I keep the `lipsum` settings as you have them, the "R" appears on page 1, and the image appears on page 3, so the same issue arises there.)

Comment: @senshin  I cannot recreate your behavior cited above.  I've edited to show updated result, using your parameters.

Comment: see [Remove page number from just one (float) page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83860/579)

Comment: Other floats that are unprocessed at the time of reaching `\rubric` *may* influence the placement of the figure.

Comment: @senshin  FYI, I am using PDFTeX or PDFLaTeX to get this result.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes When I copy the code in your answer into a new blank file `document.tex`, and then compile with `pdflatex document.tex`, I still get a document in which the red "R" appears on page 4, and the image appears at the end of the document on page 9. Maybe this is a compatibility issue or something (I'm using "pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)" fwiw). That said, I think that Werner's solution above using `\afterpage` more closely matches the result I want to achieve, but thanks for your help anyway!