# Adding a full-page image or PDF page at the first convenient opportunity

Tags: floats, pdfpages

What would be the best option to insert full page (full page height and width) images or .PDF pages such that I want it to be included in the first available empty page without interfering the flow of the current page?

For example in the MWE below, the flow of the text is broken at the point the .PDF page inserted. I can use

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\includepdf[]{files/test-page.pdf}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{figure}\includegraphics}{file.pdf}\end{figure}` depending if "full page" means over-prnting the normal page number area, you may  ned a bit more

Comment: `\afterpage{\includepdf[]{files/test-page.pdf}}` might do it (using the `afterpage` package).

Comment: With a `oneside` setting why will there be an empty page?

Comment: Maybe you want this?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116545/dynamically-insert-full-page-image-at-nearest-page-break?rq=1