# How to remove page number for the page includes "algorithm pseudo-code"?

Tags: page-numbering, algorithms, algorithmic, afterpage

I want to remove page number of the page of algorithm pseudo-code. I used `afterpage` as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83861/148579) as follows:

```
\afterpage{%
   \begin{algorithm}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        something here
      \end{algorithmic
   \end{algorithm}
}
```

However, it does not work.

**Note:** The page number is somewhere in the pseudo-code and so I want to remove the page number.

Answer (score 1):

It was done using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33013/148579) as follows:

```
\afterpage{ 
\clearpage
       \begin{algorithm}
          something here
       \end{algorithm} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage 
}
```