# Removing page numbering on the Continued float two page figures in Overleaf

Tags: floats, subfloats, page-numbering, overleaf

I have two pages consisting of two groups of related figures using the floating commands. I want to remove the page number on the second page of these two. I have tried this page [using afterpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83860/remove-page-number-from-just-one-float-page)

and tried this as well [using floatpag package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33007/suppress-page-number-for-a-single-page-that-only-contains-one-large-table) but it makes all my other figures grouped and move towards each other which I do not want. So, I only want to remove the page number (page 87 or move this page 87 to the top) of these specific two pages of the two-page floating figures (keep page number 86). Please see the pictures below. [image]

[image].

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427572/remove-header-footer-on-page-with-large-figure  Note that everypage can now be replaced with `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{...}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have checked and tried to use it. It does remove the page number, but it removes page 86 instead of 87. I have tried putting \AddThispageHook{\thispagestyle{empty}} before \begin{figure} on the page 86, on the page 87 or both , but still does not remove page number 87. any suggestion?

Comment: An MWE would have been nice, but I'll se what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As before, `\afterpage` doesn't work on float pages, and `\AddThispageHook` only delays one page.

This checks for a specific page number, which is calculated assuming the first float occurs on the next page.  (Or you could just insert the right page number for `\specialpage`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}
  \caption{This should be on page 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \rule{\textwidth}{0.8\textheight}
  \caption{This should be on page 3}
\end{figure}
\edef\specialpage{\the\numexpr \value{page}+1}% \speacialpage=2
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\ifnum\value{page}=\specialpage\relax
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
\fi}

\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for me. I applied \edef\... \fi}

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work using the suggestion of @John Kormylo. This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Scatter_plot_scRNA_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{Total read counts}
     \label{scRNA_spatial}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_spatial_gene_remaining.jpeg}
     \caption{Total read counts}
     \label{remaining_gene}
 \end{subfigure}
 
 \hfill \\
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_0_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 0}
     \label{cluster 0}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_1_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 1}
     \label{cluster 1}
 \end{subfigure}
 
 \hfill \\
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_2_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 2}
     \label{cluster 2}
 \end{subfigure} 
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_3_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 3}
     \label{cluster 3}
 \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}     

\begin{figure}[p] \ContinuedFloat  
\centering   
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_4_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 4}
     \label{cluster 4}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_5_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 5}
     \label{cluster 5}
 \end{subfigure}
 
 \hfill \\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_6_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 6}
     \label{cluster 6}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_7_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 7}
     \label{cluster 7}
 \end{subfigure}
 
 \hfill \\
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_8_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 8}
     \label{cluster 8}
 \end{subfigure} 
 \hfill 
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{scatter_cluster_9_spatial.jpeg}
     \caption{scRNA-seq cluster 9}
     \label{cluster 9}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{Scatter plots of gene read counts in Visium and scRNA-seq data (a). Read counts of genes expressed only in Visium data (b). Scatter plots for gene read counts in each cluster of scRNA-seq and in Visium data (c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l).}
    \label{scRNA clusters}
\end{figure}
\edef\specialpage{\the\numexpr \value{page}+1}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\ifnum\value{page}=\specialpage\relax
\thispagestyle{empty}
\fi}
}
```